# C-help understanding sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have difficulty understanding the line marked with "line":-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
char s[81], word[81];
int n= 0, idx= 0;

puts("Please write a sentence:");
fgets(s, 81, stdin);
while ( sscanf(&s[idx], "%s%n", word, &n) > 0 )    //line
{
    idx += n;
    puts(word);
}

return 0;
}
```

can I replace line marked with "line" with the following:

```
while ( sscanf(&s[idx], "%s%n", word, &n) )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) function returns value is the number of items in the argument list successfully read.

So, the line `while ( (sscanf(&s[idx], "%s%n", word, &n) > 0 )` means `while there is data being read, do this {}`.

The loop will break in case of type-mismatch *(which will cause the function to return `0`)*  or `EOF` in case of failure *(which is an integer constant expression of negative value - this also explains why you couldn't use just `while ((sscanf(&s[idx], "%s%n", word, &n))`, since in C any value different from `0` is considered `true` and in case of `EOF` the loop would not break)*.

Comment: How does it skip white space in the beginning?

Comment: the function reads and ignores any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters).

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf` function returns the number of items in the argument list successfully filled. `While` will get executed if `sscanf` will return a positive value.

And NO you shouldn't replace that line with

`while ( sscanf(&s[idx], "%s%n", word, &n) )`

because in case of input failure it will return `EOF` which is a non zero value makes your `while` condition to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small translation:

```
int words_read;
while (1) {

    // scscanf reads with this format one word at a time from the target buffer
    words_read = sscanf(
          &s[idx] // address of the buffer s + amount of bytes already read
        , "%s%n" // read one word
        , word // into this buffer
        , &n // save the amount bytes consumed inbto n
        );


    if (words_read <= 0) // if no words read or error then end loop
        break;

    idx += n; // add the amount of newlyt consumed bytes to idx

    puts(word); // print the word
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sscanf reads from the first arguement and writes it in given format.

```
sscanf(string to read, format, variables to store...)
```

so, as long as **s** array has something to read in it sscanf will read it and store in **word** and **n**.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [sscanf explanation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

It is taking 80characters from standard in, storing them in char[] s, then printing them one word at a time.

```
while ( sscanf(&s[idx], "%s%n", word, &n) > 0 ) //copy from "s" into "word" until space occurs
//n will be set to position of the space
//loop will iterate moving through "s" until no matching terms found or end of char array
```